# Irreducible component of representation of symmetric group modulo $p$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, $n$ an integer divisible by $p$. Consider the natural representation of the symmetric group $S_n$ with coefficients in $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ (namely to each permutation we associate its permutation matrix).

Is there a way to compute the dimension of the irreducible components of this representation ?

Comment: An algorithm of the general case is not known, there is a lot of work done on blocks of small weights (defects), i.e. less than 5.  I am also interested if anyone know the categorification program does solve the problem for abelian defect though.

Comment: This could be in mathoverflow